# Trouble with solve_ivp

Tags: python, scipy, physics

I'm currently working on an ODE problem and am having some issues with my code when using the solve_ivp function. This is my code so far:

```
def solve_ODE(N, tmax):
    tspan = (0, tmax)
    t = np.arange(0, tmax, N)
    init_conditions = np.array([rs[0], rs[1], vs[0], vs[1]])
    solution = integrate.solve_ivp(motion_function, tspan, init_conditions, t_eval=t)        
    return solution
```

The function I'm solving is a coupled ODE:

$\frac{d^{2} x}{dt^2} = - \frac{G M x}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}}$

$\frac{d^{2} y}{dt^2} = - \frac{G M y}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}}$

```
def motion_function(t, f):
    x = f[0]
    y = f[1]
    d2x_dt = -gg*mass*x / np.power((x**2 + y**2), 1.5)
    d2y_dt = -gg*mass*y / np.power((x**2 + y**2), 1.5)
    print(d2x_dt)
    print(d2y_dt)
    return d2x_dt, d2y_dt
```

The error says 'ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (4,)'

Comment: Can you post the complete error trace (no screenshot) and the actual code that calls the ODE solver

Comment: To use `solve_ivp`, you must implement the differential equations as a system of first order equations.  That is, you must express your two second order equations as four first order equations.  See, for example, https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/CoupledSpringMassSystem.html